# Slick Carousel: buttons inside of slick carousel that can overlay the carousel?

Tags: jquery, slick.js

[image: Carousel slides]

So basically I want to do something like this with Slick... I want to have the normal slides, but the thing is, is that I want to have calls to action (buttons) in them. This would normally be easy to just put the buttons in with the slides, but there is an overflow: hidden style on the carousel that can't be taken off else the other slides show up. I'm wondering how I could achieve this (the buttons slightly going outside without being cut off).

Edit: added border to carousel which is the true problem that I have... maintaining a border and getting the bottom to appear overlapping the border

Answer (score 0):

> HTML

```
    <div class="slick__slide-cta">
      <button>example</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.slick__slide-cta {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Not exactly this, but the idea would be to have the CTA area overlap the image or whatever while still contributing to the slide's overall height. Kind of hard to explain, it would be easier to show in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding a padding bottom to the .slick-list class like so:

```
.myslider .slick-list {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

The padding bottom would be the px value of half of your button, which is being overlayed. This works because it increases the height of the `.slick-list` container which has the `overlay:hidden` property on it.